# How can I pass a parameter to an ng-click function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a function in my controller that looks like the following:

AngularJS:

```
$scope.toggleClass = function(class){
    $scope.class = !$scope.class;
}
```

I want to keep it general by passing the name of the class that I want to toggle:

```
<div class="myClass">stuff</div>
<div ng-click="toggleClass(myClass)"></div>
```

But `myClass` is not being passed to the angular function. How can I get this to work? The above code works if I write it like this:

```
$scope.toggleClass = function(){
    $scope.myClass = !$scope.myClass;
}
```

But, this is obviously not general. I don't want to hard-code in the class named `myClass`.

Comment: Seems `myClass` is a simple string, rather than a variable? In the expression `toggleClass(myClass)`, myClass should be a variable on scope, or pass it as string 'myClass'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the function

```javascript
$scope.toggleClass = function(class){
    $scope.class = !$scope.class;
}
```

`$scope.class` doesn't have anything to do with the paramter `class`. It's literally a property on `$scope` called `class`. If you want to access the property on `$scope` that is *identified* by the variable `class`, you'll need to use the array-style accessor:

```javascript
$scope.toggleClass = function(class){
    $scope[class] = !$scope[class];
}
```

Note that this is not Angular specific; this is just how JavaScript works. Take the following example:

```javascript
> var obj = { a: 1, b: 2 }
> var a = 'b'
> obj.a
  1
> obj[a] // the same as saying: obj['b']
  2
```

---

Also, the code

```html
<div ng-click="toggleClass(myClass)"></div>
```

makes the assumption that there is a variable on your scope, e.g. `$scope.myClass` that evaluates to a string that has the name of the property you want to access. If you *literally* want to pass in the string `myClass`, you'd need

```html
<div ng-click="toggleClass('myClass')"></div>
```

The example doesn't make it super clear which you're looking for (since there is a class named `myClass` on the top `div`).

Comment: This is the best answer to a question that I have ever seen on this site (and there are a lot of great answers). Very clear, very concise. Thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to have helped! As I've been mentioning recently, feel free to [ping me](http://brandontilley.com/contact.html) if you have additional questions.

Comment: Isn't `class` a reserved keyword in javascript ? I'm pretty sure that would break in IE.