# Pass ng-model as a ng-click function parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is that possible to pass a `ng-model` as a function parameter? for example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel">
<button ng-click='save('button1', myModel)'>save</button>
<button ng-click='save('button2', myModel)'>save</button>
<button ng-click='save('button3', myModel)'>save</button>


....

var save = function(buttonIndex, myModel){
   myModel = buttonIndex + ' clicked';
}

....
```

In my case,I have more than one ng-model (6 sets), and I don't want to create 6 sets similar save functions in the controller which only the model is different, if I can pass the model as parameter, I would need to create a single save function is enough.

Comment: did not it work for you?

Comment: then, how to use `myModel` in `save` function?

Comment: Why are you passing the ngModel back to the controller? It will be already present in the controller inside scope. You can access it using $scope.myModel

Comment: @KK in my case, I have many buttons, I need to set different values for `ng-model` while user clicks different buttons.

Comment: @Z.Neeson, well, then just pass the value on each button: `ng-click="save('button1')"` and then in the `save` function do `$scope.myModel = buttonIndex + " clicked";`

Comment: @NewDev Yeah that's a salutation, but I have more than one `ng-model` (6 sets), and I don't want to create 6 sets similar `save` functions in the controller which only the `model` is different, if I can pass the `model` as parameter, I would need to create a single `save` function is enough.

Comment: @Z.Neeson, it seems like with every suggestion you keep adding more requirements. Can you just show the entire problem (by editing your question) from the outset?

Comment: @NewDev sorry I didn't clear my question, I've made some changes.

Comment: In your case you can do then: `$scope[myModel] = buttonIndex + " clicked";`

Comment: @NewDev in fact, I tried this approach, it doesn't seem to be working either, let me create a jsfiddle

Comment: @NewDev see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/961/)

Comment: @NewDev I believe there is a workaround, since a  `filter` can use `ng-mode` as parameter, but I don't know how does a `filter` read value from the passed `ng-model`?

Comment: @Z.Neeson, ah... well, you'll need to call save with `save('button1', 'myModel')` - i.e. the string `"myModel"` - not the value. But, I would say that this is a weird approach. What if your `ng-model` binds to a property (however nested) of an object - which it should, as a best practice - now you have to parse the expression, etc...

Comment: @NewDev hmm... indeed, I have to pass the string... I 100% agree with your opinion, it's even a bad approach, but again, if I don't want to create that many similar `save` functions, what would be the best implementation ? or how would design your approach? do you have any suggestions? thanks man.

Comment: @Z.Neeson, I don't know what your ultimate objective is (to avoid an XY problem) and can only try to deduce the structure of your overall model... but I guess, following these lines, you could create a generic function like so: `function save(val, obj, prop){ obj[prop] = val; }` and use it on any like so: `save('btn1', this, 'myModel')` or, generically: `ng-click="save('foo', my.model, 'prop1')"`

Comment: Yes exactly, your guess is correct, I used the same way like you suggested, seems a generic function is only/best practice, but a little bit weird to call `model` in that way, anyway, since there won't be a performance like issue, this approach is still acceptable. thanks again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to an ng-click function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538910/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-an-ng-click-function)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already having your model in $scope you could use it directly, otherwise Create a function in your corresponding controller like this,

```
$scope.save = function(model) {
//do whatever you want
}
```

Example:

[`Pass argument in ng-click`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/n7n1tw77/)

Comment: however, in this function, if I put `model = 123`, it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: what do you mean by model= 123? and it does not work?

Comment: model is associated to an `input`, I need set `model = 123` to make that `input` content displays 123.

Comment: @Z.Neeson check the example

Comment: This isn't what I want, please see my updates in the question, I want to set particular context for an `input` according to the button clicked.

Comment: @Z.Neeson It's the same thing you are talking about :) just pass the data and bind it

Comment: Yes I got your point, in my case, I have more than one ng-model (6 sets), and I don't want to create 6 sets similar save functions in the controller which only the model is different, if I can pass the model as parameter, I would need to create a single save function is enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is a easy and fast solution for little operations like your:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel">
<button ng-click="myModel='button1 clicked'">save1</button>
<button ng-click="myModel='button2 clicked'">save2</button>
<button ng-click="myModel='button3 clicked'">save3</button>
```

it is not passing parameters, but in the on-click definition you can do also normal code.

http://jsfiddle.net/cwne0stq/

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar need. In an ionic form, I have 6 fields of same type/data for which the values could be set by button, and I didn't want to duplicate the function in the controller. I needed to be able to call a function on button click, passing a field (ng-model) name as a parameter, and wasn't working. But finally this works. Took a bit to figure it out since I'm new to angular/ionic. Hope it helps someone because there wasn't a lot of info on this.

First couple fields example:

```
<div class="item item-input-inset">
  <label class="item item-input-wrapper">       
  <i class="icon ion-edit placeholder-icon"></i>
  <input type="text" placeholder="00:00" ng-model="formdata.time1">
  </label>
  <button class="button" ng-click="settime('time1')">Now</button>
</div>

<div class="item item-input-inset">
  <label class="item item-input-wrapper">       
  <i class="icon ion-edit placeholder-icon"></i>
  <input type="text" placeholder="00:00" ng-model="formdata.time2">
  </label>
  <button class="button" ng-click="settime('time2')">Now</button>
</div>
```

And in controller:

```
.controller('YourCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.formdata = {};

  $scope.settime = function(field){
    var d = new Date();
    $scope.formdata[field] = d.getUTCHours()+':'+(d.getUTCMinutes() < 10 ? '0'+d.getUTCMinutes():d.getUTCMinutes());
  }

});
```

If you need to pass a value from a button, you could add parameter:

```
<div class="item item-input-inset">
  <label class="item item-input-wrapper">       
  <i class="icon ion-edit placeholder-icon"></i>
  <input type="text" ng-model="formdata.yourfield">
  </label>
  <button class="button" ng-click="yourfunction('This Value','yourfield')">This</button>
  <button class="button" ng-click="yourfunction('That Value','yourfield')">That</button>
</div>
```

And same in controller:

```
.controller('YourCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.formdata = {};

  $scope.yourfunction = function(value,field){
    $scope.formdata[field] = value;
  }

});
```